# i can't sync gradle in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

today i was trying to sync gradle android studio but this happend

[ERROR PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roDy9.png)

and one more thing: i living in iran so i have some sanction problems but i use dns for this issue and still nothing change

as i say i tray dns bun nothig change...

Comment: For someone with network restriction problems, the problem was the firewall. Disabling the firewall solved the issue. Otherwise it could be needed to add some code (i.e.: in "setting.gradle") or remove some file.

Answer (score 0):

It ain't look like network difficulty but if you face it in the future it might work.

Set this proxy on your android studio. (File -> Settings -> Appereance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Http Proxy -> Manual Proxy Configuration)

https://github.com/freedomofdevelopers/fod

```
Host name: fodev.org
Port number: 8118
```